# How to Store Images in Laravel in the 'public/images' Directory Instead of 'storage/app/public/images'?

Tags: laravel, laravel-8

I'm facing an issue in my Laravel application where images are getting stored in the "storage/app/public/images" directory, even though I'm attempting to store them directly in the "public/images" directory within the **`store`** method.

**Details:**

1. **Laravel Version:** I'm using Laravel version 8.83.27.
2. **Current Behavior:** Currently, when I upload images using the **`store`** method, they are automatically stored in the "storage/app/public/images" directory. This is not the behavior I desire.
3. **Desired Behavior:** I want the images to be stored directly in the "public/images" directory within my Laravel project.
4. **Code Sample:** Below is the relevant code snippet for my **`store`** method:

```
public function store(CreateStoryRequest $request)
{
    $validatedData = $request->validated();

    if ($request->hasFile('image')) {
        $image = $request->file('image');
        $imageName = $image->getClientOriginalName(); // Obtenez le nom d'origine du fichier
        $image->storeAs('public/images', $imageName); // Stockez l'image dans public/images
        $validatedData['image'] = $imageName; // Ajoutez le nom de l'image aux données validées
    }

    // Créez un nouveau client en utilisant les données validées
    $story = Story::create($validatedData);

    // Redirigez l'utilisateur vers la page de détails du client nouvellement créé
    return redirect()->route('story.index')->with('success', 'histoire créée avec succès');
}
```

// Provide the code snippet of your store method here

**Error Messages:** I'm not receiving any error messages, but the images are not being stored in the desired location.
**PS :**  I was working on a different project where images were originally stored in the "public/images" directory. To debug an issue, I ran the `php artisan storage:link` command from the Laravel documentation. After running this command, images started getting saved in the "storage/app/public/images" directory instead of "public/images," which is not what I wanted.

I then abandoned that project but later copied its essential files (controllers, views, routes, models, migrations, seeders, and requests) to a new project. Unfortunately, the same image storage issue persists in the new project.

By providing these details, I hope to get assistance in resolving this issue and understanding why images are being stored in the "storage/app/public/images" directory despite my efforts to store them in "public/images" within the **`store`** method.

I have taken several steps to resolve this issue, including:

Updating Configuration: I reviewed my Laravel configuration files, specifically filesystems.php, to ensure that the default disk is correctly set to "public."

php
Copy code

Filesystem Configuration: I also modified the "filesystem.php" configuration file as follows:

```
<?php

return [

    /*
    |--------------------------------------------------------------------------
    | Default Filesystem Disk
    |--------------------------------------------------------------------------
    |
    | Here you may specify the default filesystem disk that should be used
    | by the framework. The "local" disk, as well as a variety of cloud
    | based disks are available to your application. Just store away!
    |
    */

    'default' => env('FILESYSTEM_DRIVER', 'local'),

    /*
    |--------------------------------------------------------------------------
    | Filesystem Disks
    |--------------------------------------------------------------------------
    |
    | Here you may configure as many filesystem "disks" as you wish, and you
    | may even configure multiple disks of the same driver. Defaults have
    | been setup for each driver as an example of the required options.
    |
    | Supported Drivers: "local", "ftp", "sftp", "s3"
    |
    */

    'disks' => [

        'local' => [
            'driver' => 'local',
            'root' => storage_path('app'),
        ],

        'public' => [
            'driver' => 'local',
            'root' => public_path(),
            'url' => env('APP_URL').'/images',
            'visibility' => 'public',
        ],

        's3' => [
            'driver' => 's3',
            'key' => env('AWS_ACCESS_KEY_ID'),
            'secret' => env('AWS_SECRET_ACCESS_KEY'),
            'region' => env('AWS_DEFAULT_REGION'),
            'bucket' => env('AWS_BUCKET'),
            'url' => env('AWS_URL'),
            'endpoint' => env('AWS_ENDPOINT'),
        ],

    ],

    /*
    |--------------------------------------------------------------------------
    | Symbolic Links
    |--------------------------------------------------------------------------
    |
    | Here you may configure the symbolic links that will be created when the
    | `storage:link` Artisan command is executed. The array keys should be
    | the locations of the links and the values should be their targets.
    |
    */

    'links' => [
        public_path('storage') => storage_path('app/public'),
    ],

];
```

Expected Outcome:

I expected that, after implementing these steps, the images uploaded using the store method would be stored directly in the "public/images" directory within my Laravel project.

Actual Result:

Despite these efforts, the images are still being stored in the "storage/app/public/images" directory. This is not the intended behavior, and I'm seeking assistance in understanding why the images are not being stored in the desired location and how to resolve this issue.

Comment: run `php artisan storage link`

Comment: Are you using the `Storage` facade? Did you try `Storage::disk('public')->put('avatars/1', $content);` where disk is public?

Comment: that's same after after you have symblink! using ``php artisan storage:link``

Answer (score 1):

To directly put images in the public folder you can use the move() method on the request.

```
// Note that image is the input name
$request->image->move(public_path('images'), $imageName);
```